# how to fetch gender(male/ female) in blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a form for my laravel project it has photo and gender fields. I used a checkbox and a price field I stored in database successfully I can display the image and the price but i can not display the gender that was selected by user.
If some one can help me please!
Thanks.

I tried this code:

```
@foreach($file as $choice)
   {{ $choice['male'] || $choice['female'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: what type of values stored in database for gender?

Answer (score 0):

```
      {{Auth::user()->gender }}


or

@foreach($file as $choice)
      {{$choice->gender }}
    @endforeach
```

Comment: hello I used an if condition like this: @if($choice->gender == 1)
                                 {{ 'male' }}
                            @elseif($choice->gender == 0)
                            {{ 'female' }}
                            @endif     because in my database it store like that if it is male it store 1 and if it is female it store 0 but when I want to show it in my browser from blade file it show both the male and female if some one can help me please do it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing `string` in gender filed

```
@foreach($file as $choice)
      {{$choice->gender=="male" ? "Male" : "Female }}
@endforeach
```

if you are storing `boolean` like 0 for male or 1 for female in gender filed

```
@foreach($file as $choice)
      {{$choice->gender==0 ? "Male" : "Female }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: First tank you for your answer next I added this code on my blade file but it did not work . if you can please share your controller code with me because I  use compact method on my index function

Comment: what you are storing in gender field means gender="male" or gender=1 then give you db table structure and controller code